# What does 'pinoc' mean?

Tags: philip-k-dick, the-man-in-the-high-castle

What does 'pinoc' in *The Man in the High Castle* mean? I had the feeling it is someone subordinate but I did not find an exact explanation in the book.

Comment: Could you give some context?  A quote from the book?

Comment: Sorry @Chenmunka, I couldn't quote the book as I didn't have it in english. Turns out, had I read it in english, there wouldn't have been any question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an epithet for the puppet government of the Pacific States of America:

> Since he had never been able to make out Wyndam-Matson's relationship to the
>   pinocs — the puppet white government at Sacramento — he could not fathom his ex-employer's power to sway the real authorities, the Japanese.

Although I do not think this is ever explicitly mentioned in the book, I believe the word derives from the name of the fictional puppet [Pinocchio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinocchio).

Comment: Thank you! I looked it up why I was so confused and turns out in the translation I was reading it said: "..Wyndam-Matson's relationship to the pinocs AND the puppet white government at Sacramento.."
Now it makes much more sense ;)

Comment: I agree with the other answer, and believe “pinoc” is a reference to the typically longer noses of caucasians compared to east asians.

Answer (score 1):

It means an underling or non-Japanese. As it says on page 7 of my copy:

> he could not fathom his ex-employer's power to sway the real authorities, the Japanese. The LJC was pinoc run.